# How did Stansfield explain the woman shot in the bathtub?

Tags: plot-explanation, leon-the-professional

When that guy who stole the drugs lies to Stansfield in *Leon: The Professional* (1994), they come back the other day and shoot his entire family, including his wife in the bathtub with headphones on.

Later on, when Mathilda goes to her old place, Stansfield comes in with other two agents explaining what happened and how he shot that guy, because 'he was reaching for the gun'.

OK, they might have believed that, but how did he explain why unarmed naked women with headphones laying in a bathtub were shot? The daughter and the boy too. And he got away with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply, in-universe he didn't explain it at all.

However, had something like that happened in real life, it could most likely be explained as "[collateral damage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_damage)".  However, in real life he would have been suspended pending an investigation, which would have conflicted with the pace of the movie.  So, this is what is referred to as "[suspension of disbelief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief)".  You just accept what the characters are doing without questioning the "how".

Answer (score 0):

He's a lying cop.

He said that the guy was reaching for a gun. What gun? The one he shot that women and kids with. He was a drug dealer. It's more common for a spouse to kill his family than a cop shooting people because the guy was dealing HIS drugs. Case opened and closed.